# How to print child elements of mounted component in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I would like to be able to print the results of wrapper.find('some selector')

I am mounting a react component

```js
wrapper = mount(
                <SomeReactComponent />
            );
```

And I am able to print the whole contents of wrapper with console.log(wrapper.debug()) but I was wondering if there is some way to print specific results. I tried console.log(wrapper.find('some selector').debug()) but nothing prints.

How can I print more specific parts of the html rendered in wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `mount` method I guess that you are using enzyme for rendering.

In that case, you can use simple `find` that has one argument selector. That selector is regular query selector.

```js
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
console.log(wrapper.find('.my-component').at(0).html())
```

**NOTE**:
If you have more components that have `my-component` it will return array of elements so it is needed to have that `.at(0)` to select one item.

`html()` will print out plain html code.

API Reference:
https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html